# Ejercicio con libreria Datetime

Tags: python

tengo un rato haciendo este ejercicio del curso y la verdad estoy vuelto un ocho, me encantaría que me ayudaran, tengo que decir cuántos días falta para mi cumpleaños y que día de la semana cae.

```
import datetime

fecha_hoy = datetime.datetime.today()
dia_cumpleanos = int(input("¿Qué día cumples? "))
mes_cumpleanos = int(input("¿Qué mes cumples? "))
ano_estamos = int(input("¿En qué año estamos? "))

fecha_cumpleanos = datetime.date(day=dia_cumpleanos, month=mes_cumpleanos, year=ano_estamos)

dias_un_ano = datetime.timedelta(days=365)
resta_dias_cumple = fecha_cumpleanos - dias_un_ano

resta_total = datetime.timedelta(resta_dias_cumple)

tiempo_para_cumple = fecha_hoy - resta_total
dia_semana_cumple = fecha_cumpleanos.weekday()
week_day_cumple = ""

if dia_semana_cumple == 0:
    week_day_cumple = "Lunes"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 1:
    week_day_cumple = "Martes"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 2:
    week_day_cumple = "Miércoles"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 3:
    week_day_cumple = "Jueves"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 4:
    week_day_cumple = "Viernes"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 5:
    week_day_cumple = "Sábado"
elif dia_semana_cumple == 6:
    week_day_cumple = "Domingo"

print("Faltan {} días para tu cumple, un {}".format(tiempo_para_cumple.strftime("%d"), week_day_cumple))
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema con el código? ¿no se ejecuta? ¿no da el resultado correcto? Es importante que las preguntas estén bien estructuradas y se entienda qué es lo que se busca y los problemas/dificultades que se están encontrando. Lee [ask] para más información.

Comment: El error que da al ejecutar el código es muy clarificante, por favor, completa la pregunta para cumplir los estándares mínimos y así poder responder